# How do I batch renumber files in sequence?

Tags: ruby, bash, batch-processing

I have a sequence of image files that look like this:

```
image-149454.jpg
image-149455.jpg
```

I have some other images that I want to append to the end of the sequence where it left off but currently they are numbered from 0 (i.e. `image-000000` to `image-010000`).

What's a script I could use to rename those new images starting from a certain number and going on, in this case 149456 and onwards?

Comment: "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try something like this. You just have to adjust the offset and add a string in front of the name, just as you need it.

```
x=1
for i in *.jpg; do
    temp=$(printf "%08d.jpg" ${x}) #padding since you seem to want it
    mv ${i} ${temp}
    let x=x+1
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an untested solution in Python. This should change all of the files in a directory to have sequentially higher numbers than the other.

To use it enter: `script.py dir1 dir2`

Assuming the original files have the higher number (149455) are in dir1 and the new files start from 000000 are in dir2:

```
import os, sys, re

max_image = 0
# check if current (with higher numbers) and other (with lower) directory is given
if len(sys.argv) == 3:
    for files in os.listdir(sys.argv[1]): # first dir is current
        if files.endswith(".jpg"):
            #for all jpgs get the max
            m = re.search("\-(\d+)", files)
            number = int(m.group(1))
            if max_image < number:
                max_image = number

    for files in os.listdir(sys.argv[2]): # second dir is other
        if files.endswith(".jpg"):
            #get current start point
            m = re.search("\-(\d+)", files)
            number = int(m.group(1))
            os.rename(files, "image-" + str(number + max_image)+".jpg") # add the max from current folder
```

Comment: im going to try this but i've never used python before-- just to be clear where you marked [1] and [2] I should put the paths to the directories in question? relative or absolute paths?

Comment: i get invalid syntax on line 6 "if"?

Comment: If you are copying the code, remember all of the indentation should match. For example, there might be spaces and tabs mixed together.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pure bash solution which uses the last image sequence as your starting point (per your request):

```
#!/bin/bash
last_seq=$(ls image-* | tail -1 | sort -n | cut -c7-) # grab the sequence number
last_seq=${last_seq%.jpg} # remove the trailing .jpg
if [ -z $last_seq ] ; then
  echo "Unable to obtain the last image sequence number"
  exit 1
fi
for image in image-0*.jpg ; do
   [ -f ${image} ] || break  # In case no files match image-0*.jpg
   let last_seq=last_seq+1
   mv -v ${image} image-$(printf "%06d.jpg" ${last_seq})
done
```

Here's how it worked locally:

before the run:

```
~/tmp › ls -l
total 80
-rw-r--r-- 1 dyoung staff     0 Dec 12 10:20 image-00000.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 dyoung staff     0 Dec 12 10:20 image-01000.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 dyoung staff     0 Dec 12 10:05 image-14908.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 dyoung staff     0 Dec 12 10:05 image-14909.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 dyoung staff     0 Dec 12 10:05 image-14910.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 dyoung staff   418 Dec 12 10:24 testh.sh
```

during the run:

```
~/tmp › sh ./testh.sh
image-00000.jpg -> image-14911.jpg
image-01000.jpg -> image-14912.jpg
```

after the run:

```
~/tmp › ls -l
total 80
-rw-r--r-- 1 dyoung staff     0 Dec 12 10:05 image-14908.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 dyoung staff     0 Dec 12 10:05 image-14909.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 dyoung staff     0 Dec 12 10:05 image-14910.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 dyoung staff     0 Dec 12 10:20 image-14911.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 dyoung staff     0 Dec 12 10:20 image-14912.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 dyoung staff   429 Dec 12 12:25 testh.sh
```

Comment: i get "unable to obtain the last image sequence number" ? are there variables in here i should be filling in? it looked complete

Comment: as is, it needs to be run from the directory where your images files reside, and assumes they match file names of `image-*` as per your original post.  I did test this locally and it works here.

Comment: i guess im a little confused about how to point the second half to the right place (where the filenames to be changed are) in your code it says for image in image-0*.jpg  which would seem like it would be looking in the same directory its running last_seq from which wouldnt work?

Comment: your original post implied that the images are all in the same directory, and that the files you wanted to rename matched image-0*.jpg, is that not the case?  If not, then you need to rephrase your question to include those crucial details.

Comment: sorry i was really unclear-- here's the simplest formulation: I have a bunch of image files numbered image-000001.jpg up to image-013872.jpg I want to rename them starting with the first one (image-000001.jpg) to start as image-158872.jpg and then +1 from there. that's all! no need to get last_seq or anything

Comment: look.  If you put all the files in one directory and run that script _from that directory_, it will work.  You need `last_seq` to obtain the highest image number, otherwise, how would you know where to start renaming them?

Comment: ive tried that and it didn't work-- i don't know what i'm screwing up but im trying to follow your directions; apologies if I'm being a bother. I tried to make the problem simpler by the above comment by telling you I happen to know where to start from because I know the highest current file number which is image-158872.jpg

Comment: I've updated the reply to show how I ran it locally... hopefully that clarifies it.  If not, than I don't know what it is you are trying to do.

Comment: ok thanks for your response- another answer in this thread solved my problem, in fact. but i appreciate the time you spent clarifying it for me, thank you

Comment: That's not what you asked for, but I'm glad this is resolved.  Next time, please be specific about what you want.